# how to find number of times query executed?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, database-performance

I have few queries running in Oracle 11g database from application those are repeatable queries. I want to find number of times the query executed for the day and time it took for each execution based on sql_id or sql_text? Is there a way to find this?

Comment: Not unless you do something to log it.

Comment: You can get some summary details from v$sqlarea.  not sure about per-execution stats.

Answer (score 2):

The number of executions is in the AWR reports.  Which means it can probably also be derived from a DBA_HIST_ table but I don't know which one.  Based on your previous question I assume you have AWR licensed.

```
--Find the SQL_ID.  If not in shared_pool it should be in a historical table.
select * from v$sql where sql_fulltext like ...;
select * from dba_hist_sqltext where sql_text like ...;

--Find the begin and end snapshot periods.
--Be careful here, I've seen some weird timezone issues, it can be annoyingly
--difficult to get the exact period of time you want.
select * from dba_hist_snapshot order by begin_interval_time desc;

--Get AWR report.
select dbms_workload_repository.awr_sql_report_text(l_dbid => 3037785498
  , l_inst_num => 1, l_bid => 53007, l_eid => 53020, l_sqlid => '57pfs5p8xc07w')
from dual;


WORKLOAD REPOSITORY SQL Report

Snapshot Period Summary

...

    Plan Hash           Total Elapsed                 1st Capture   Last Capture
#   Value                    Time(ms)    Executions       Snap ID        Snap ID
--- ---------------- ---------------- ------------- ------------- --------------
1   1329243004                    376           552         53008          53018

...
```

Comment: I really appreciate you solution but Is it possible to break it done by each execution some how? like                                   plan hash value    elapsed_time(ms)  time                               ---------------    --------------     ------------                        1329243004             10                02-Feb-2012 22:10:30           1329243004             0.9               02-Feb-2012 22:11:10        This way?

Comment: It depends on your query, but probably not.  Most of the performance views work by sampling or aggregating.  Otherwise the data would be too large.  One of my databases at work generates more than 2GB of AWR information per day.  To get incredibly fine-grained data you will need to use tracing.  But in general I think that sampling is good enough.  If something isn't sampled it's probably not relevant to performance.

Answer (score 0):

you can check query execution in AWR report.

[image]