# Finding number of executions of Oracle SQL between two snap ids

Tags: sql, database, oracle

For a Oracle SQL query that is not present in the AWR report how do I find its number of executions between two snap ids?

Comment: check if you enabled active session history - query `V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find number of times query executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533421/how-to-find-number-of-times-query-executed)

Comment: haki, the V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY is active and can be queried. jonearles, the question is different, here the query is not figuring in the AWR report as it is not the top 10-20 executed or resource consuming and we want to find its number of executions not for the day but for duration between two AWR snap ids. This is like digging for information that is not presented in the AWR snapshots but which may be stored in the tables

Comment: great, then you have a `snap_id` column, an `sql_id` column ... query away...

Comment: BTW - you can always open `awrrpt.sql` and look at the queries.

Comment: Haki, I researched online that awrrpt.sql can be used to generate AWR report but could not find any link to generate it for a specific query. Issue is as I mentioned in my comment before that the query is not making it in top 15-20 queries that are shown in the AWR report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a query id '91jn8cfvpmkm9'
AWR snap begin id 19863
AWR snap end id 19864
db_id 702590136

following query provided the number of executions and other details for the query of interest

select output from table (dbms_workload_repository.awr_sql_report_text(l_dbid => 702590136
  , l_inst_num => 1, l_bid => 19863, l_eid => 19864, l_sqlid => '91jn8cfvpmkm9'));

Part of the output is below

....
....

```
        Plan Hash           Total Elapsed                 1st Capture   Last Capture
     Value                    Time(ms)    Executions       Snap ID        Snap ID
    --- ---------------- ---------------- ------------- ------------- --------------
     54069910                   81,459           256         19864          19864
```

....
....

Following post helped me in getting the answer.
[how to find number of times query executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533421/how-to-find-number-of-times-query-executed?lq=1)